# How to reduce the load / no of queries on MySql Database

Tags: query

I'm using a simple function to generate an auto increment custom field value and it is working well except that it is making my WordPress back end a bit slow.

Can somebody help me reduce the load on my MySql Server. Here is the script i'm using ...

```
function updateNumbers() {
    /* numbering the published posts: preparation: create an array with the ID in sequence of publication date, /
    / save the number in custom field 'incr_number' of post with ID  /
    / to show in post (within the loop) use <?php echo get_post_meta($post->ID,'incr_number',true); ?>
    / alchymyth 2010 */
    global $wpdb;
    $querystr = "SELECT $wpdb->posts.* FROM $wpdb->posts WHERE $wpdb->posts.post_status = 'publish' AND $wpdb->posts.post_type = 'post' ";
    $pageposts = $wpdb->get_results($querystr, OBJECT);
    $counts = 0 ;
    if ($pageposts):
        foreach ($pageposts as $post):
            setup_postdata($post);

            $counts++;

            add_post_meta($post->ID, 'sayings_number', $counts, true);
            update_post_meta($post->ID, 'sayings_number', $counts);

        endforeach;

    endif;
}  

add_action ( 'publish_post', 'updateNumbers');
add_action ( 'deleted_post', 'updateNumbers' );
add_action ( 'edit_post', 'updateNumbers' );
```

Comment: I wonder why you need this and how you're using it with your loops. Maybe there are other ways?

Comment: I simply add this in my function.php , it add a custom field  to every post i create with a  value  which increment for every post i create .

Comment: yes that's a description of what your current code snippet does, but how and where do you use the  `sayings_number` meta value ? Any code snippets for that ? More relevant info and context, increases the changes of other users here coming up with an alternative solution.

Comment: All i need is to insert a meta value for sayings_number  which automatically increment when a new post is created. My First post has a custom field "sayings_number" with value 1 , the second post value 2  and so on ...

Comment: I use this value to display article number and for some other purpose.  the above code works perfectly but increases the load on the server.
Mainly because of the query `$querystr = "SELECT $wpdb->posts.* FROM $wpdb->posts WHERE $wpdb->posts.post_status = 'publish' AND $wpdb->posts.post_type = 'post' ";`